# Is there any harm to having a duplicate index in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.1

I have the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE join_table (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  col_a integer NOT NULL,
  col_b integer NOT NULL
)

CREATE INDEX index_on_col_a ON join_table USING btree (col_a);
CREATE INDEX index_on_col_b ON join_table USING btree (col_b);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_on_col_a_and_col_b ON join_table USING btree (col_a, col_b);
```

There are also foreign keys on col_a and col_b.

Clearly `index_on_col_a` is no longer needed,
but is there a cost or benefit to keeping or deleting it?

My guess is;

- keeping it will slow down inserts
- selects using just `col_a` may be faster if I keep it

Comment: Seems like you already know the answer?

Comment: hmm... should I avoid guessing in questions? maybe someone has something more firm than a guess.

Comment: It depends on the case, Better write performance or query perfor
But from my personal opinions, we need drop index index_on_col_a

Comment: thanks @francs. I usually would. I just wanted to get some verification that I'm right. I guess I'll just remove it.

Comment: We have discussed this case [in great detail at dba.SE recently](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/3684).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can drop the index on `col_a`. PostgreSQL is able to use the combined index if you query on `col_a` and is also able to use the index if you query on `col_a` and `col_b`. These query types can use the combined index:

```
WHERE col_a = 'val'
WHERE col_a = 'val' AND col_b = 'val'
```

The combined index cannot be used to query only `col_b` or an `OR` junction of `col_a` and `col_b`. So the additional index over `col_b` can make sense if you frequently have queries querying only `col_b`.

Edit: So: you don't have an advantage creating `index_on_col_a`, but you have a slower write speed. Drop it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I agree with the other answer on dropping the index on col_a, sometimes index combinations could be so large that, the index on (col_a, col_b) takes more disk pages, compared to col_a index, which could lead to more I/O on disk. Please use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` to find the actual rows read, and total cost (represented with equivalent of I/O ops).

If there are more `col_b` per `col_a` (per 1 col_a, there are >100 col_b or so), then having the `col_a` will be helpful. if you are doing range queries, this will be more useful in that case. All these make sense if you really care about very low latency during reads.